# MacBook boots automatically when opening lid. Feature or problem?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup

When my 13" Retina MacBook running Yosemite is powered off and I open the lid, it immediately starts booting up... without pressing the power button. Is this a new feature (maybe part of Yosemite) or is my MacBook misbehaving?

If it's a feature, I'm not necessarily sure that I dislike it... but I definitely find it jarring. Can I disable it?

(*And yes, I can assure you, it really is shut down and not asleep.*)

Comment: are you sure it was off, or only hibernating?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Yep, totally sure. Completely off. I just double checked.

Comment: Then you have a 2020 generation of computers. Others are still stuck on reacquiring human interface to press a mechanical button to bring them alive.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Ahh... so you're saying my MacBook has travelled back in time to enhance my life? Good enough.

Comment: Seriously, it is not possible, otherwise why would you need the power button?, it is just tricking you to be off, while it is hibernating.

Answer (score 1):

Rarely a Power button is broken, but it can happen, so you can not turn it off.

But to check your instant wake up with lid open check in the Console if it was just hibernating.

Open Console in your utility folder and look for times after you turned it OFF.

You might see some activity few hours later while you were sleeping, that would tell you it was just hibernating.

Something like `2/3/15 6:02:40.000 AM kernel[0]: Wake reason: EC.SleepTimer (SleepTimer)` shows that mine was just hibernating -not off.

And here is a full sequence when Turning it OFF then 3 minutes later Turning in on with Power Button.

2/3/15 9:54:26.567 AM **shutdown**[529]: SHUTDOWN_TIME: 1422986066 567166

2/3/15 9:54:26.000 AM kernel[0]: Kext loading now disabled.

2/3/15 9:54:26.000 AM kernel[0]: Kext unloading now disabled.

2/3/15 9:54:26.000 AM kernel[0]: Kext autounloading now disabled.

2/3/15 **9:54**:26.000 AM kernel[0]: Kernel requests now disabled.

2/3/15 **9:57**:58.000 AM **bootlog**[0]: BOOT_TIME 1422986278 0